# Including dependency containing cucumber(jUnit4) brakes maven-surefire-plugin test detection in jUnit5 project

Tags: java, maven, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin, cucumber-junit

I have specific dependency in my project which uses cucumber 6.2.0 and runes on jUnit4 with vintage engine. The dependency changes maven-surefire-plugin behavior when added to project. If I exclude cucumber from dependency maven-surefire-plugin detects tests again.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>some.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>some.dependency</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
         <exclusion>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I’ve adopted that dependency project in separate branch so cucumber runs on junit5 and it solves the issue. I still don’t understand what gets inherited and brakes surefire plugin when running cucumber on vintage engine.
I cannot reproduce the Issue completely and I’m not allowed to share client code. What I can share is part of pom that refers to jUnit and cucumber.

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <cucumber.version>6.2.0</cucumber.version>
    <junit.platform.version>1.7.0-M1</junit.platform.version>
    <junit.jupiter.version>5.7.0-M1</junit.jupiter.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- cucumber -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
      <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
      <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
      <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
      <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <!-- cucumber runs on JUnit4, so we need the compatibility engine -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Code runs with Apache Maven 3.8.1 and Java version: 11.

Comment: Please make a full working example on Github......

Comment: I’ve come up to new conclusions and changed my question. I’m not allowed to share client code but I have shared a part of pom related to cucumber and jUnit dependencies.

Comment: Have a look at the docs on how to make a minimal reproducer.  You should be able to do this without including proprietary code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example